# How to change Widget style in SWT, of existing widget

Tags: swt

How to change `Widget` style in `SWT`, of existing widget, Means i am working on `ProgressBar` and i want to change it's style `SWT.VERTICAL` from `SWT.HORIZONTAL`

Comment: I am creating demo for ProgressBar if click on Vertical Button it should be Vertical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, styles are fixed once the control has been created.

In some cases SWT may use a completely different native control to implement the SWT control depending on the style flags. For example on macOS a `Combo` with the `SWT.READ_ONLY` style uses a different macOS control to a read/write `Combo`. This would make allowing you to change the style very complex.

Comment: So, is there any solution, without disposing it?

Comment: No there is no solution without disposing or creating everything to begin with and making some things not visible until you need them.